# Unable to connect to a remote apache ignite node

Tags: java, ignite

I am running a simple code to test Apache Ignite distributed cache. One node
is on a server and the other one is run locally when I start a java program.

```
public class HelloIgnite {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello Ignite");
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("example-cache.xml");
        // get or create cache
        IgniteCache<Integer, String> cache =
ignite.getOrCreateCache("testCache");
        // put some cache elements
        for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
            cache.put(i, Integer.toString(i));
        }
        // get them from the cache and write to the console
        for(int i =1; i<= 100; i++){
            System.out.println("Cache get:"+ cache.get(i));
        }
        ignite.close();

    }
}
```

The above is the simple code I am testing. And here is my ignite config

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="ignite.cfg"
class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean
class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">

                    <bean
class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>

                                <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47509</value>
                                <value>SERVER_IP:47500..47509</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="joinTimeout" value="1000"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I start the node on the server using `ignite.sh -p example-cache.xml` first and
then run the above code locally. However, instead of putting values to the
cache and printing them, when I run the code, it is stuck showing this
message:

> [13:40:46] Configured failure handler:
>   [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0,
>   super=AbstractFailureHandler
>   [ignoredFailureTypes=[SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED,
>   SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]]] [13:40:48] Message queue limit
>   is set to 0 which may lead to potential OOMEs when running cache
>   operations in FULL_ASYNC or PRIMARY_SYNC modes due to message queues
>   growth on sender and receiver sides. [13:40:49] Security status
>   [authentication=off, tls/ssl=off]

On the node I started on the server, It is repeatedly printing the following
to the console:

> [11:48:28] Topology snapshot [ver=56, locNode=cd55466e, servers=2,
>   clients=0, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=40, offheap=28.0GB, heap=34.0GB]
>   [11:48:28] Topology snapshot [ver=57, locNode=cd55466e, servers=1,
>   clients=0, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=32, offheap=25.0GB, heap=30.0GB]
>   [11:48:34] Joining node doesn't have encryption data
>   [node=02e2f398-b5b8-4044-83dd-53755e28f94e]

However, when I stop the server node, the local node starts to run properly
and print the values.

How can I resolve this? what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I recommend removing 127.0.0.1 from IP finder and also running in verbose mode (`IGNITE_QUIET=false`), sharing output with us.

Comment: @alamar getting this message now on local node

`
[2019-11-22 15:28:13,654][WARN ][main][TcpDiscoverySpi] Node has not been connected to topology and will repeat join process. Check remote nodes logs for possible error messages. Note that large topology may require significant time to start. Increase 'TcpDiscoverySpi.networkTimeout' configuration property if getting this message on the starting nodes [networkTimeout=10000]
`

Comment: Where is your server node deployed? Please, check that you are not facing the firewall issues and the specified ports are available: 47500-47509 as well as 47100.

Comment: It is deployed on a remote server. And I checked it and it the ports are open with no firewall

Comment: the issue is the node I start locally is joining and leaving the cluster as it can be seen on the log output of the server nodes:

`[16:41:27] Topology snapshot [ver=17, locNode=f3331aed, servers=3, clients=0, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=56, offheap=41.0GB, heap=48.0GB]
[16:41:27] Topology snapshot [ver=18, locNode=f3331aed, servers=2, clients=0, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=48, offheap=38.0GB, heap=44.0GB]`